# SortedDictionary key Object duplicate Problem

Tags: c#

I have a SortedDictionary with Object as key, which implements the IComparable interface,
but the result is not correct.
here is the code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;

namespace TestApp {

public class Program
{

    public class UserPrice : IComparable<UserPrice>
    {
        public string Wxid { get; set; }

        public int Num { get; set; }
        public int Price{ get; set; }

        public DateTime PriceTime { get; set; }

        public int CompareTo(UserPrice other)
        {
            if (Wxid == other.Wxid)
            {
                return 0;
            }
            if (Price != other.Price)
            {
                return other.Price.CompareTo(Price);
            }
            return PriceTime.CompareTo(other.PriceTime);
        }
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return String.Format("wxid={0}, num={1}, price={2}, priceTime={3}", Wxid, Num, Price, PriceTime);
        }
    }
    
    
    
        private SortedDictionary<UserPrice, int> sortedPriceDict = new SortedDictionary<UserPrice, int>();
        private BlockingCollection<UserPrice> chan = new BlockingCollection<UserPrice>();
    
        private void MockMessage()
        {
            sortedPriceDict = new SortedDictionary<UserPrice, int>();

            var task = Task.Run((Action)MockRecvMsg);
            for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                var j = i;
                Task.Run(() => MockSendMsg(j));
            }
            task.Wait();    
        }

        private void MockRecvMsg()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                var p = chan.Take();
                sortedPriceDict[p] = 1;
                //Console.WriteLine(sortedPriceDict.Count + "," + p);
                if(sortedPriceDict.Count > 10)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
            foreach(var up in sortedPriceDict){
                Console.WriteLine(up);
            }
        }

    
        private async void MockSendMsg(int i)
        {
            var wxId = String.Format("user_{0}", i);
            var rand = new Random();
            var basePrice = 320;
            while(true)
            {
                var up = new UserPrice();
                up.Wxid = wxId;
                up.Price = rand.Next(basePrice, basePrice + 100) * 100;
                up.Num = rand.Next(1, 10);
                up.PriceTime = DateTime.Now;
                //Console.WriteLine(up);
                chan.Add(up);
                await Task.Delay(rand.Next(1, 5) * 1000);
            }
        }
    
    
    public static void Main()
    {
        var main = new Program();
        main.MockMessage();
    }
}

}
```

I want to sort by [Price desc, PriceTime asc], user price with the same Wxid should by unique in the SortedDictionary,  I start 10 Tasks to produce messages from 10 users, and 1 consumer to save the messages into the sortedDictionary, but after run for a while, the program will stop, because the dictionary's count is > 10, so what's wrong with my code ? Do I miss anything?

Comment: Do you ever break out of your `while(true)` loop inside `MockSendMsg()`?

Comment: You MUST implement `GetHashCode()`  and `IEquatable` for the type you're putting in a hashing container, else it all goes horribly wrong. If you don't do that, it will do things like assuming that two objects are different if they have different references, even if their contents are identical.

Comment: @AstridE. no break

Comment: @MatthewWatson I ever implemented  those methods，it doesn‘t work

Comment: When I run your code the sorting seems correct (although all `PriceTime` values in entries with matching `Price` value are identical, so you can't see any ordering there), but there are `Wxid` duplicates in the dictionary.

Comment: You always seem to add the value `1` to your dictionary. Could you rather say that your dictionary is a `Dictionary<string, UserPrice>` and simply let `Wxid` value be the `key` when trying to add items to your dictionary? Do you need the `1` value for something?

Comment: @AstridE.  Dictionary<string, UserPrice> doesn't not have sort function, the value 1 doesn't make sense, because SortedDictionary will sort by the key.

Comment: True, my previous suggestion would ruin the sorting; nevermind about that. I'm afraid I can't help out here. I do believe Matthew Watson's comment is important, though - it doesn't seem like the uniqueness of the `Wxid` is taken into consideration. Also, you may want to switch from `SortedDictionary` to `SortedSet`, so that you don't need to care about the `1` for every entry.